# Sorting of large dataset fails to complete

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, memory, query-optimization

This is a followup to [debugging a mysql insert fail in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526817/debugging-a-mysql-insert-fail-in-php) as I now have time to continue on the project.

I have three tables in this problem:
840,721 posters in poster_data
58,506 poster categories in poster_categories
17,629,007 (17 million+) poster/category combinations in poster_prodcat

Based on the Efficient Pagination presentation by Yahoo!, I'm trying to add a category rank number to poster_prodcat so we can page by rank as opposed to using limits and offsets. Despite cranking up my php mysql connect timeout to 3600 (crazy I know) and turning of the php timeout, the ordering never seems to complete. maybe several tens to maybe a hundred thousand or so, but never the full 17,000,000 set.

Here's the script:

```
$sql1="select distinct apcatnum from poster_prodcat";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

while ($cats = mysql_fetch_array ($result1)) {
  $sql2 = "SELECT poster_data.apnumber,poster_data.aptitle 
           FROM poster_prodcat,poster_data 
           WHERE poster_prodcat.apcatnum ='$cats[apcatnum]' 
           AND poster_data.apnumber = poster_prodcat.apnumber 
           ORDER BY aptitle ASC";
  $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
  $ordernum=1;

  while ($order = mysql_fetch_array ($result2)) {
    $sql3 = "UPDATE poster_prodcat SET catorder='$ordernum' 
             WHERE apnumber='$order[apnumber]' AND apcatnum='$cats[apcatnum]'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    $ordernum++;
    }
  }
```

This is on a 2 gig server that also hosts the site. The timeouts are long and the server's not crashing, so I don't see what's stopping it from completing. Can I do this on this server, or since this is a once a month or so operation, should I just create some massive memory EC2 instance, do the sorting there and downloaded the massaged tables?

Thanks.

Here's the structure of poster_data (with some fields removed that aren't involved in the selects):

```
CREATE  TABLE  `poster_data` (
`apnumber` mediumint( 8  )  NOT  NULL DEFAULT  '0',
`aptitle` varchar( 255  )  NOT  NULL DEFAULT  '',
`aptype` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
[snip]
UNIQUE  KEY  `posterid` (  `apnumber`  ) ,
KEY  `aptitle` (  `aptitle`  ) ,
KEY  `aptype` (  `aptype`  ) ,
KEY  `title_type` (  `aptitle` ,  `aptype`  )  ) ENGINE  = InnoDB;
```

poster_prodcat:

```
CREATE TABLE `poster_prodcat` (
`apcatnum` mediumint( 8 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`apnumber` mediumint( 8 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`catorder` mediumint( 7 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY ( `apcatnum` , `apnumber` ) ,
KEY `apcatnum` ( `apcatnum` ) ,
KEY `apnumber` ( `apnumber` ) ,
KEY `catorder` ( `catorder` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB /*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (apcatnum) PARTITIONS 10 */;
```

Comment: Show us the plan of your query and tables ddl creation script.

Comment: @Chris Buckler: The update is needed to add the rank number to the poster data by category. So yes, every record needs an update. Again, only done once a month or so when new data is downloaded.

Comment: @Ian - Just tried something like this out with 2 million records and it only takes about 15 seconds.  I think that you may be getting caught in an infinit loop or something.  Could you make it output when a counter is at 250k,1M, 5M? Just so we can make sure its not getting hung up...

Comment: Any effect on time if you remove that ORDER BY?

Comment: @Chris Buckler: I'm wondering if it's taking so long due to a lack of inno key buffer size since the 2 gig server's running the web server and mail as well. Those three inno tables (the only three inno tables I have) have a data size of 687.8M and a measly buffer pool of 128.0M. Obviously that's slamming performance. Gonna fire up a large EC2 instance for an hour and see if it takes a few seconds there.

Comment: @chris fired up an ec2 instance today with 7 gigs of ram, mysql 5.5 and the large innodb my.conf. After 4 hours we're at 13.8 million updates out of the 17 million and counting.

Comment: @Chris Buckler: If you're updating 2 million rows in 15 seconds, and you're using a loop like Ian, then you're sustaining about 133,000 transactions per second. According to the Wikipedia article Ian should expect about 200 transactions per second. (I'm too tired to look up MySQL docs.) At 200 TPS, I think his update will take about 25 hours. Can someone double-check that arithmetic? It's been a long 14 days, and I'm not sharp today.

Answer (score 0):

```
  while ($order = mysql_fetch_array ($result2)) {
    $sql3 = "UPDATE poster_prodcat SET catorder='$ordernum' 
             WHERE apnumber='$order[apnumber]' AND apcatnum='$cats[apcatnum]'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    $ordernum++;
    }
  }
```

Does this mean you're executing 17 million separate transactions? If you can sustain a thousand transactions per second, this part alone will take about 5 hours, right?

Wikipedia (readily available, but not what I'd consider authoritative) says this about [innodb transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB).

> When operating in fully ACID-compliant
>   modes, InnoDB must do a flush to disk
>   at least once per transaction, though
>   it will combine flushes for inserts
>   from multiple connections. For typical
>   rotating hard drives or arrays, this
>   will impose a limit of about 200
>   update transactions per second.

Comment: Yeah, when I ran the EC2 server just to handle this it took several hours. Can't think of a better way to handle this.

Comment: @Ian: I looked up "Efficient Pagination presentation by Yahoo!" and found this url: http://www.slideshare.net/Eweaver/efficient-pagination-using-mysql . I don't see anything there that resembles what you're trying to do. Am I looking at the right presentation?

Comment: on pg. 14 they talk about paging through results using another type of order value instead of "Limit M,N". In my case I'm creating order values for thousands of categories.

Comment: So you're creating a new column to hold a sort order, instead of using the id numbers like are in the slides, right? Their method will probably work fine, but by using existing id numbers, they're not having to update 17 million rows.